Enemy Bullet group sprites are not displaying on screen
For some reason the update() method and draw() method of the sprite.Sprite.Group() not working correctly, both methods are working for the player_bullet and other sprite groups that I create, but the enemy_bullet group is not displayed on the screen when I use the update() method of the Group() which the pygame itself provided, the bullets are drawn on screen.
The bullet module:
import pygame as pg


from .player import player

from graphic.resolution_setting import screen

from .tools.image_func import create_image

from icecream import ic

SCALE = 0.03

PLAYER_BULLET_IMG_PATH = "material/Icons/player/player-bullet-frame1.png"

PLAYER_BULLET_IMG = create_image(PLAYER_BULLET_IMG_PATH, SCALE)


###########################################################################################


ENEMY_BULLET_IMG_PATH = "material/Icons/enemy/enemy-bullet.png"

ENEMY_BULLET_IMG = create_image(ENEMY_BULLET_IMG_PATH, SCALE)


class PlayerBullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        
        
        self.x, self.y = (player.player_x + player.image.get_width() // 2), (player.player_y + player.image.get_height() // 2)
        
        self.image = PLAYER_BULLET_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
    
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -4)
        
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.kill()
    
player_bullet = pg.sprite.Group()




class EnemyBullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self,
                 x: int,
                 y: int) -> None:
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        self.image = ENEMY_BULLET_IMG
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        
    def update(self) -> None:
        self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
        
        if self.rect.y > 0:
            self.kill()
        
        
enemy_bullet = pg.sprite.Group()

The game screen module:
import pygame as pg
import random

from graphic.resolution_setting import screen

from objects.player import player_group, player
from objects.bullet import player_bullet, enemy_bullet, EnemyBullet
from objects.enemy import enemy_gp, mystery_gp, Mystery


from objects.tools.text import Text
from objects.tools.custom_timer import unlimited_gun_power_timer
from objects.tools.pause import pause


from sfx.sound_list import sounds

from icecream import ic

FONT_PATH = "material/font/Pixelify_Sans/PixelifySans-VariableFont_wght.ttf"

class GameScreen:
    
    
    def __init__(self,
                 screen,
                 width: int,
                 height: int) -> None:
        
        self.screen = screen
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        self.score_label = Text(f"SCORE: {player.score}",
                                FONT_PATH,
                                30,
                                "#06ff06",
                                "black",
                                80,
                                20)
        
        self.lives_label = Text(f"LIVES: {player.health}",
                                FONT_PATH,
                                30,
                                "#06ff06",
                                "black",
                                730,
                                20)
    
    
    @staticmethod
    def enemy_bullet_collide(enemy_group) -> None:
    
        hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_group, player_bullet, False, True)
            
        for enemy in hits:
            
            if enemy.enemy_type == 1:
                player.score += 1
            elif enemy.enemy_type == 2:
                player.score += 2
            elif enemy.enemy_type == 3:
                player.score += 3
            elif enemy.enemy_type == 4:
                sounds.play_power_up_sound()
                player.score += 10
                player.unlimited_gun = True #TODO - Add another power to shoot
                unlimited_gun_power_timer.activate()
                
                
            enemy.is_dead = True
            enemy.set_death_image()
            
        for enemy in enemy_group:
            if enemy.is_dead:
                enemy.death()
    
    
    def draw(self) -> None:
        self.screen.fill('black')
        
        ######################################################
        player_group.update()
        player_group.draw(self.screen)
        
        ################################################################################
        if len(player_bullet) >= 1:    #TODO - Add power effect for unlimited magazine
            player_bullet.update()
            player_bullet.draw(self.screen)   
        ##################################################################################
        
        enemy_gp.draw(self.screen)
        
        ##################################################################################
        self.enemy_bullet_collide(enemy_gp)
        
        ####################################################################################
        self.score_label.draw(self.screen)
        self.score_label.update(f"SCORE: {player.score}")
        
        self.lives_label.draw(self.screen)
        self.lives_label.update(f"LIVES: {player.health}")
        ######################################################################################
        
        for enemy in enemy_gp.sprites():
            fire = random.choices([1,0], [0.1, 99.9])[0]
            
            if fire == 1:
                ic(enemy)
                ic(fire)
                ic(enemy.rect.x, enemy.rect.y)
                enemy_bullet.add(EnemyBullet(enemy.rect.x + enemy.image.get_width() // 2, enemy.rect.y + enemy.image.get_height() // 2))
                ic(len(enemy_bullet.sprites()))
        
        
        enemy_bullet.update()
        enemy_bullet.draw(self.screen)
        
        
        if len(enemy_gp.sprites()) == 0:
            player.is_win = True
            pause.change_pause_state()
            sounds.play_victory_sound()
            
        #########################################################################################
        
        # if pg.sprite.groupcollide(player_group, enemy_gp, False, False):
        #     player.death()
        #     pause.change_pause_state() #FIXME - Fix the issue with the collide the player with the enemies which gives error
        
        ###########################################################################################################
        
        if len(mystery_gp.sprites()) == 0:
            trigger = random.choices([1,0], [0.5, 99.5])[0]
            
            if trigger and player.unlimited_gun == False:
                mystery_gp.add(Mystery())
                sounds.play_mystery_sound()
                
        mystery_gp.update()
        mystery_gp.draw(self.screen)
        
        self.enemy_bullet_collide(mystery_gp)
        
        ############################################################################################################
        
        
game = GameScreen(screen.display(),
                  screen.get_width(),
                  screen.get_height())


So I Don't know where my code has a problem that causes the enemy_bullet not to be displayed on the screen.
